# Symfony 2 Swift_Mailer multiple recipents

Tags: email, symfony, swiftmailer

I am using symfony 2.1 and I have **form** for adding e-mails (with table in Database).Something like Newsletter. 
And i want to send group email for all recipents from this table. How to put all this email`s from database table into **setTo**.

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject('Hello Email')
                    ->setFrom('form@form.pl')
                    ->setTo('??')
                    ->setBody(
                        $this->renderView(
                            'NewAdminBundle:Msg:index.html.twig',
                            array('singlelist' => $list

                          )
                        )
                    )
                ;
                $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `array` to the `setTo()` method:

```
  setTo(
       array(
         'receiver@domain.org',
         'other@domain.org' => 'A name'
    ))
```

See also http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

Comment: OK, but I want to use there a variable from base with emails list.

Comment: @Cre3k you can use an array you previously made with your database contacts, then pass it to the 'setTo' method.